# Can I use conda and pip3 interchangeably to install Python packages?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I don't understand why some Python packages are installed using `conda` and some by using `pip3`.

Are these just different installers from different developers but doing the same thing?

Can I use them interchangeably to install Python packages?

For example:

```
conda create -n mtl python=3.6 anaconda
conda activate mtl
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends upon your familiarity with pip and conda and how package installation interacts between the two methods. If you are a relative new user of conda and python, I would recommend using only conda to install your packages. YMMV depending upon your experience with both.

See the following two documents that explain the relationship between conda and pip in more detail:

[Using pip in a conda environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) & [Understanding Conda and Pip](https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-conda-and-pip/)

From the first article:

> Running conda after pip has the potential to overwrite and potentially break packages installed via pip. Similarly, pip may upgrade or remove a package which a conda-installed package requires. In some cases these breakages are cosmetic, where a few files are present that should have been removed, but in other cases the environment may evolve into an unusable state.
>
> There are a few steps which can be used to avoid broken environments when using conda and pip together. One surefire method is to only use conda packages.

`conda install <package_name>` will be constrained to your use within conda environment. If you delete your conda installation, those packages will be removed as well.

Generally, conda will modify your $PATH so that this isolates the package installation from your system somewhat.

When you use `pip3 install <package_name>`, you are potentially affecting your system Python installation. Especially if you use `sudo` or `sudo -H` to install the Python package.

I am not certain if it is a best practice; but, when I am using `pip3`, I generally use the command syntax of `pip3 install --user <package_name>` which will "Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically in the `~/.local/` directory."

Again, I try to take some precaution to isolate my package changes from the system's Python installation.

I consider it a matter of personal preference as to which method `conda` vs. `pip3` is "best".

Comment: Thank you. But if I am already in the mtl environment, then wouldnt the pip3 command install it in said environment?

Comment: @Kong conda would be the preferred method unless you really know what you are doing, or can't get the package from using the conda install method. See my updates.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and those links are extremely helpful.